# Symfony: The best practice for decoupling storage

Tags: database, storage, symfony

What is considered the best practice when it comes to decoupling your bundle from its storage?

I created a bundle for storing key-value pairs and named it `ConfigBundle`.

It defines an API for accessing this data.

In its configuration I made it possible to define a service responsible for storing this data, with its own API defined by a StoragEInterface. 
This service has to implement a proper interface of course.

I defined this service in another bundle: `ConfigDbBundle`, which is using Doctrine to create a proper entity in the database. This way I decoupled the logic from the storage in my `ConfigBundle`.

But it made me think - would it be a good idea to do this for EVERY bundle I create?

That could easily double the number of bundles I have to register, and even if it isn't much of an additional overhead, I asked myself if there is another, better practice for this.

Comment: Isn't Doctrine itself an abstraction layer between storage and code?

Comment: This is a good point, I might be really creating an abstraction layer over already existing abstraction layer - I came up with this solution for the `ConfigBundle` because I didn't want for Doctrine to create entity in database automagically, after registration of `ConfigBundle` in the Kernel. Having a separate bundle for storage seemed "clean", but I'm not sure if this is a proper solution, hence I ask for the "best practice". Also one more thing: I wanted to easily use another storage backend for only this one entity.

Comment: Then it might be a good idea.

Comment: Did you check this project: https://github.com/doctrine/KeyValueStore ?

Comment: Hint: not everything needs to be in a bundle (think libs). 
Hint 2: a bundle can integrate more than one lib.